# Finding the limit of an expression

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $[0,1]$ such that $f(1) = 1$. If the derivative of $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, evaluate

$$ \lim_{y\to \infty} \int_0^1 yx^{y}f(x) \ dx$$

I have tried performing integration by parts on the function but I realised that I am unable to proceed further from there. I also tried to play around with the limit by letting f(x) to be a known function that satisfies the criteria. It turns out that the limit approaches $1$ for$\ f(x) = x^{2}\ $. Looking at similar questions posted here, I tried making use of the Extreme Value Theorem. However, all I could conclude is that the integral is bounded by some value$\ M\ $.

Comment: There is no indeterminate form. Answer should be $0$. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry. Just edited the limit! It should tend towards infinity instead of 0.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please update the post to show your attempt at the problem, or this will be closed. We don't like questions that look like copy-and-paste homework.

Comment: Sorry! I just edited it to include my attempts at solving it!

Comment: I think the limit is f(1) for any continuous f. By Weierstrass approximation it is enough to prove this when f is a polynomial. So take $f(x)=x^{N}$. A simple integration by parts shows that the limit is 1. I don't think differentiability plays any role.